# php regex to replace last dot

Tags: preg-replace

`http://i.imgur.com/KKtAU8X.jpg`

preg_replace to change be like

`http://i.imgur.com/KKtAU8Xt.jpg`

replace last dot to `t`.

try code

```
/\.([^.]*)$/  or /(.*)\.([^.]*)$/
```

add it remove `.jpg` too!

I need to keep `.jpg`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ cat test.php
<?
$url = 'http://i.imgur.com/KKtAU8X.jpg';
$newUrl = preg_replace('#^(.+)\.([\w]+)$#i', '$1t.$2', $url);
var_dump($url, $newUrl);

$ php test.php
string(30) "http://i.imgur.com/KKtAU8X.jpg"
string(31) "http://i.imgur.com/KKtAU8Xt.jpg"
```